# How to check if telegram user is bot and not an user?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to get the user values of member who joins my super group.
What I want to do is when bot joins my group I want to ban him forever, and if it's a regular user and not a bot do nothing.

I tried for some days and some other credentials but it didn't work, seems like the condition is wrong.

I'm using `Telegram.Bot` library

Here is my approach so far:

```
if (e.Message.Type == MessageType.ChatMembersAdded && e.Message.From.IsBot)
{
  await bot.RestrictChatMemberAsync(GroupId, e.Message.From.Id, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(20), false, false, false, false);
}
```

Comment: Ask it for it most liked Pokemon and check if the Answer is within the range of known Pokemons

Comment: can you translate your codes to words please ?.. didnt understand you

Comment: Do an abstract Turing test with new members

Comment: im not famiiliar with abstractst do you mean create new class ? can you please provide example srry for the newbiew question

Comment: My bad. A Turing Test is a way to test an AI or software for its plausible humanity. A question like "Which Pokemon do you like best" will usually not be answered correctly by a bot, a human should find this task (with Google) easy. It was meant as a playful approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over `update.message.new_chat_members` which is an array of `User` and check for the value of `newUser.IsBot` to filter out the bots added to your chat.